# dynamic cast doesn't recognize member

Tags: c++, object, dynamic-cast

I'm working on a project where I have 2 classes: Room and EventRoom
EventRoom inherits from Room and have a few more members.

In my code I do this(tmpPtr is a Room-pointer):

```
if(eventRoom)
     tmpPtr = dynamic_cast<EventRoom*>(tmpPtr);
```

and later when I try this:

```
if(line == "false;")
     tmpPtr->setComplete(false);
```

I get compilation errors. *setComplete* is a member of EventRoom

**Short version:** I want to create objects of type Room, and in some cases EventRoom. The code currently works for Room only, but 90% of the code would be identical for EventRoom. Any way of using the same code? (with dynamic_cast or something similiar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `tmpPtr` to be an `EventRoot` pointer.

```
EventRoom* tmpPtr;

if(eventRoom)
     tmpPtr = dynamic_cast<EventRoom*>(tmpPtr);
```

You can only call `Room` public methods on a `Room` pointer. You cannot call `EventRoom`-only methods.

Comment: but then will it work for Room as well? or am I going to need 2 different pointers, 1 for each sittuation?

Comment: @Yoan yes, it will work for `Room` because `EventRoom` **is-a** `Room`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Depends on what is meant by "work with `Room` as well." It's not possible to assing a `Room*` into an `EventRoom*` (without a cast).

Answer (score 1):

The code which has to work with both `Room` and `EventRoom` (that is, it only works with the `Room` interface), has to work through a pointer statically typed `Room*`.

The code which uses specifics of `EventRoom` has to work through a pointer statically typed `EventRoom*`. So example code could look like this:

```
void someFunction(Room *myRoom) {
  // doRoomStuff must be a function declared in Room.
  myRoom->doRoomStuff();

  // Try to determin if the room is an event room or not. This will
  // occur at runtime.
  EventRoom *myEventRoom = dynamic_cast<EventRoom*>(myRoom);

  if (myEventRoom) {
    // doEventRoomStuff is a function declared in EventRoom. You cannot call
    // myRoom->doEventRoomStuff even if 'myRoom' points to an object that is
    // actually an EventRoom. You must do that through a pointer of type
    // EventRoom.
    myEventRoom->doEventRoomStuff();

    // doRoomStuff2 is a function that is declared in Room. Since every 
    // EventRoom is also a room, every EventRoom can do everything that
    // rooms can do.
    myEventRoom->doRoomStuff2();
  }

  myRoom->doRoomStuff3();
}
```

You can access `Room` members through a `EventRoom*` variable, but not vice versa.

Comment: This was an excellent post to begin with. I was writing something very similar, but after seeing your post, I chose to edit it to add some commentary to your code, to emphasize things a little more.